# griddb-python package is giving this error

Tags: python, griddb

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building '_griddb_python' extension
swigging src/griddb.i to src/griddb_wrap.cpp
swig -python -DSWIGWORDSIZE64 -c++ -outdir . -Isrc -o src/griddb_wrap.cpp src/griddb.i
unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

I want to use griddb-python package in my code, where I have to work accessing gridbdb cluster which I have configured locally.